# Rows hidden on dropdown selection become unhidden upon selection from second dropdown

Tags: vba, excel, rows

In Sheet "Input" I have two Dropdown lists. The first one is to select between payoffs and the second is to select between observation types.

In the Sheet "Output" the rows are hidden.

When I select one payoff the specified rows are hidden which is good but after selecting the observation type the rows of the payoff are unhidden which is bad.

I'm using the following code:

```
With Sheets("Output")
Sheets("Output").Rows("112:137").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("138:151").Hidden = False
Select Case Target.Value
Case "Bonus Capped Single Index"
Sheets("Output").Rows("112:154").Hidden = True
Case "Bonus Capped Single Share"
Sheets("Output").Rows("112:154").Hidden = True
Case "Bonus Uncapped Single Index"
Sheets("Output").Rows("112:154").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("256:257").Hidden = True
Case "Bonus Uncapped Single Share"
Sheets("Output").Rows("112:154").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("256:257").Hidden = True
Case "Bonus Uncapped Single Index"
Sheets("Output").Rows("112:154").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("256:257").Hidden = True
Case "Bonus Capped Worst of Indices"
Sheets("Output").Rows("112:154").Hidden = True
Case "Bonus Capped Worst of Shares"
Sheets("Output").Rows("112:154").Hidden = True
Case "Bonus Uncapped Worst of Indices"
Sheets("Output").Rows("112:154").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("256:257").Hidden = True
Case "Bonus Uncapped Worst of Shares"
Sheets("Output").Rows("112:154").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("256:257").Hidden = True
Case "Phoenix Single Share"
Sheets("Output").Rows("116:133").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("139").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("254:257").Hidden = True    
Case "Phoenix Single Index"
Sheets("Output").Rows("116:133").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("138").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("254:257").Hidden = True
Case "Phoenix Yeti Single Index"
Sheets("Output").Rows("138").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("116:131").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("254:257").Hidden = True
Case "Phoenix Yeti Single Share"
Sheets("Output").Rows("139").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("116:131").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("254:257").Hidden = True
Case "Worst of Indices Phoenix"
Sheets("Output").Rows("138").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("254:257").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("116:131").Hidden = True
Case "Worst of Shares Phoenix"
Sheets("Output").Rows("138").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("254:257").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("116:131").Hidden = True
Case "Worst of Shares Phoenix Yeti"
Sheets("Output").Rows("116:131").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("138").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("254:257").Hidden = True
Case "Worst of Indices Phoenix Yeti"
Sheets("Output").Rows("139").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("116:131").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("254:257").Hidden = True
Case "Autocall Single Index"
Sheets("Output").Rows("254:257").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("112:131").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("138").Hidden = True
Case "Autocall Single Share"
Sheets("Output").Rows("254:257").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("112:131").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("139").Hidden = True
Case "Autocall Worst of Shares"
Sheets("Output").Rows("254:257").Hidden = True    
Sheets("Output").Rows("112:131").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("139").Hidden = True
Case "Autocall Worst of Indices"
Sheets("Output").Rows("254:257").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("112:131").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("138").Hidden = True
Case "Reverse Convertible Single Share"
Sheets("Output").Rows("116:133").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("138:154").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("254:257").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("162:164").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("173:175").Hidden = True
Case "Reverse Convertible Single Index"
Sheets("Output").Rows("116:133").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("138:154").Hidden = True    
Sheets("Output").Rows("254:257").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("162:164").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("173:175").Hidden = True
Case "Worst of Shares Reverse Convertible"
Sheets("Output").Rows("116:133").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("138:154").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("254:257").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("162:164").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("173:175").Hidden = True
Case "Worst of Indices Reverse Convertible"
Sheets("Output").Rows("116:133").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("138:154").Hidden = True    
Sheets("Output").Rows("254:257").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("162:164").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("173:175").Hidden = True
Case "Coupon Linker Index"
Sheets("Output").Rows("160:164").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("254:257").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("171:175").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("116:133").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("138:154").Hidden = True
Case "Fix Coupon Express Single Index"
Sheets("Output").Rows("116:133").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("254:257").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("136:137").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("139").Hidden = True
Case "Fix Coupon Express Single Share"
Sheets("Output").Rows("116:133").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("254:257").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("136:137").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("138").Hidden = True
Case "Fix Coupon Worst of Shares"
Sheets("Output").Rows("116:133").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("254:257").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("136:137").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("138").Hidden = True
Case "Fix Coupon Worst of Indices"
Sheets("Output").Rows("116:133").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("254:257").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("136:137").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("138").Hidden = True
Case Else
Sheets("Output").Rows("112:137").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("138:151").Hidden = False
End Select
End With

With Sheets("Output") 'Observation and delivery
Sheets("Output").Rows("158:212").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("246:253").Hidden = False
Select Case Target.Value
Case "American Cash"
Sheets("Output").Rows("177:212").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("165").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("176").Hidden = True
Case "American Physical"
Sheets("Output").Rows("162:164").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("177:212").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("173:175").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("246:253").Hidden = True
Case "European Cash"
Sheets("Output").Rows("170:172").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("159:164").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("165").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("176").Hidden = True
Case "European Physical"
Sheets("Output").Rows("159:164").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("170:175").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("246:258").Hidden = True
Case Else
Sheets("Output").Rows("158:212").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("246:253").Hidden = False
End Select
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I am guessing thats because when you change observation type dropdown , the value in the Target is a observation type. this value does not match with any of the cases in the payoff. hence the `case else` is run which shows all the rows.

Comment: At a quick glance, and more of a comment than solution, you use `With Sheets("Output")` but then go on and declare it each time, instead of just doing `.Rows("1:2")...` No need to keep repeating that.

Comment: @excelnewbie, you already posted this question [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098986/unable-to-hide-rows-correctly-vba) and a very similar one [on the 9th of december](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41056861/sheet-refresh-sheet-doesnt-accept-entered-values). You should either try to follow up answers/suggestions already given to you and/or show some efforts from your part instead of merely repeating the same code over and over again

Comment: @nightcrawler23 thank you for you comment but it doesn't help. A window is opened where the line "Select Case Target.Value" is marked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you gave used Target in your code, i am guessing you used Worksheet_Change module to run your code. However your code should look something like this to achieve your required behaviour. *Also, see my comment above*.

i have used A1 and A2 as the position of the dropdown lists. You need to change these accordingly

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not (Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing) Then
        Call showObservation(Target.value)  '@nightcrawler23
        ElseIf Not (Intersect(Range("A2"), Target) Is Nothing) Then
        Call showPayoff(Target.value)  '@nightcrawler23
    End If
End Sub

Sub showPayoff(myCase as String)  '@nightcrawler23
    With Sheets("Output")
        .Rows("112:137").Hidden = False
        .Rows("138:151").Hidden = False
        Select Case myCase  '@nightcrawler23
            Case "Bonus Capped Single Index"
                .Rows("112:154").Hidden = True
            Case "Bonus Capped Single Share"
                .Rows("112:154").Hidden = True
            Case "Bonus Uncapped Single Index"
                .Rows("112:154").Hidden = True
                .Rows("256:257").Hidden = True
            Case "Bonus Uncapped Single Share"
                .Rows("112:154").Hidden = True
                .Rows("256:257").Hidden = True
            Case "Bonus Uncapped Single Index"
                .Rows("112:154").Hidden = True
                .Rows("256:257").Hidden = True
            Case "Bonus Capped Worst of Indices"
                .Rows("112:154").Hidden = True
            '...
            '...
            '...
            '...
        End Select
    End With
End Sub

Sub showObservation(myCase as String) '@nightcrawler23
    With Sheets("Output") 'Observation and delivery
        .Rows("158:212").Hidden = False
        .Rows("246:253").Hidden = False

        Select Case myCase '@nightcrawler23
            Case "American Cash"
                .Rows("177:212").Hidden = True
                .Rows("165").Hidden = True
                .Rows("176").Hidden = True
            Case "American Physical"
                .Rows("162:164").Hidden = True
                .Rows("177:212").Hidden = True
                .Rows("173:175").Hidden = True
                .Rows("246:253").Hidden = True
            '...
            '...
            '...
            '...
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but it doesn't work. A debug window will be opened where the line "Select Case Target.Value" is marked

Comment: See my changes above. You need to send the Target.Value to the subs as they do not have the variable Target

Comment: yes I thought I already have thanked you but maybe i forgot to click on enter. Sorry for disturbing you but could you help me on another problem? I have two Cases which hide rows and one case intersects the other one. e.g. one case says hide rows 100:158 and the other one says unhide 120:138. Do you know how to solve it? I would appreciate your help so much. Thanks a lot.

Comment: if your problem was solved, could please accept the answer. For your other problem, i don't understand what the issue is. However you can submit another question. Thanks